# Running Generated scripts throws Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table '' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2014, sql-server-2017

I am trying to move a database from a server with SQL Server 2017 Express edition to another server with SQL Server 2014 Standard Edition. Database backup/restore was not an option because of version problem so I had to generate scripts for entire database and run them on new server.

Since my total database is about 4 GB (with data) so I first created the schema scripts only and ran them on target server, which worked perfectly fine. Then I created the data only scripts with database compatibility set to SQL Server 2014 Express.

When I run these scripts on the target system, I get a lot of errors like below.

> Cannot insert explicit value for identity column in table '' when IDENTITY_INSERT is set to OFF.

I know the problem is because identity column is set to true for the tables for which I am facing this issue and then I am supplying values for identity column. I want to use the same values for identity columns that are their in my old server's database.

How do I successfully restore this database?

Comment: Set [IDENTITY_INSERT ON](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/set-identity-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Answer (score 0):

Before inserting to an identity column you must allow it with `set identity_insert <table name> on`. Check this command. After you are done, `set identity insert off`.

Maybe there is some option to restore identities. In regular SQL Server restore runs OK.

Comment: But how do i do this? like i said, my scripts are generated through `generate scripts` command of SQL Server Management Studio and the file is about 4 GB big. I can't manually turn on/off the identity insert. Any chance to automate this?

Comment: @WAQ if there isn't an option to select when generating the script (and I though there was under advanced options), but otherwise you would have to manually add this, but its only two lines per table - so not that difficult.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it is possible to temporarily remove an identity property from the source table before generating scripts and restore it later. If it is possible.